# Make a specified length of an array when using new with pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to make a specified length array using new. Here's the code example:

```
int n = 13
int* a = new int[n];
int g = *(&a + 1) - a; // array length
```

Last line gets ridiculous numbers even when I specified length of this int array.

Comment: Why don't you just use a `std::vector`??

Comment: Any reason why you don't use the language features, instead of this horrible code? Just try `std::vector<int>`

Comment: `int g = *(&a + 1) - a;` - try that in a code review == instant fail! (at least where *I* work).

Comment: `*(&a + 1)` invokes *undefined behavior*  - you cannot calculate the array size from a pointer, any such attempts are completely broken

Comment: Okay thanks, everyone! I will look into how vectors work, I'm completely new into the game!

Comment: `int g = n;` should give you want you want.  But use `std::vector`.

Comment: @BloodyGoldfish `int g = *(&a + 1) - a; // array length` -- If there was a standard way to get the number of items when `new[ ]` is used, wouldn't you think that the C++ language would have a nicer, easier, way to get that value?  If I were a new programmer, I would be perplexed as to why I have to do anything looking like this to come up with a simple value.  I would expect `num_newed(a)` or something like that, already available.  Bottom line -- there is no way to get this value in a standard manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointer array can not have the same specified length, using vectors instead does the trick.

```
int n = 13;
vector<int> a;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    a.push_back(i); //! Insert needed values instead of i if required
cout<<"vector a length is "<<a.size();
```